# I have a single horizontal bar chart in chartjs. I want the datasets to have different sizes but not be centered, they always start on the same axis?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

```
const config = {
        type: 'bar',
        plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
        data,
        options: {
          indexAxis: 'y',
          aspectRatio: 7,
          scales: {
            x: {
              tooltipFormat: 'HH:mm',
              type: 'time',
              time: {
                unit: 'hour',
                displayFormats: {
                  hour: 'HH:mm'
                },

              },
              min: '00:00',
              max: '24:00',
              grid: {
                display: false,
                drawBorder: true,
                drawTicks: true,
                borderColor: 'white'
              },
              ticks: {
                display: true
              },

            },
            y: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              stacked: true,
              grid: {

                display: false,
                drawBorder: false,
                drawTicks: false,
                borderColor: 'white'
              },
              ticks: {
                display: false
              },
            },
          },

          plugins: {

            tooltip: {
              callbacks: {
                title: context => {

                  const d = new Date(context[0].parsed._custom.start);
                  const e = new Date(context[0].parsed._custom.end);
                  const startHours = d.toLocaleString([], {
                    hour: "2-digit",
                    minute: "2-digit"
                  });
                  const endHours = e.toLocaleString([], {
                    hour: "2-digit",
                    minute: "2-digit"
                  });

                  if (context[0].dataset.label === 'PAISES') {
                    return (context[0].raw.entryType + ": " + startHours);
                  }
                  else if (context[0].dataset.label === 'VEICULOS') {
                    return "DAS " + startHours + " ÀS " + endHours + "\n" + context[0].raw.kms;
                  }
                  else {
                    return context[0].dataset.label + "\n" + "DAS " + startHours + " ÀS " + endHours;
                  }
                },
                label: context => {
                  return "";
                },
              }
            },

            datalabels: {
              anchor: 'center',
              align: 'bottom',
              labels: {
                value: {
                  color: 'blue'
                }
              }
            },

            zoom: {

              zoom: {
                drag: {
                  enabled: true,
                },

              },

              wheel: {
                enabled: true,
                modifierKey: 'ctrl'

              },

              mode: 'xy', scaleMode: 'x',


            },
            autocolors: false,
            legend: {
              display: false
            },
          }
        },
      };
```

in this case the rest dataset (blue) had to come down instead of being centered. I don't know if I need to add any configuration. If I set barpercentage or categorypercentage or barthickness it never stays aligned at the bottom. always at the center

[image: image here]